# Why this query with geography data type works in SSMS but doesn't work in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

I have a query that works well in SSMS but doesn't work in SSRS. Here it is in SSMS:

```
 declare @or geography = 0xE6100000010CAE8BFC28BCE4474067A89189898A5EC0
 declare @dest int =1500

 select FirstName+' '+LastName As CustomerName, SpatialLocation as CustomerLocation from Person.Address PA
 left join Person.BusinessEntityAddress PBA ON PBA.AddressID=PA.AddressID
 left join Sales.Customer SC ON SC.CustomerID = PBA.BusinessEntityID  
 left join Sales.Store SS ON SS.BusinessEntityID=SC.StoreID
 left join Person.Person PP ON PP.BusinessEntityID = PBA.BusinessEntityID
 WHERE CustomerID IS NOT NULL 
 AND @dest >= (@or.STDistance(SpatialLocation)*0.62)
```

And I use the following in SSRS:

```
 select FirstName+' '+LastName As CustomerName, SpatialLocation as CustomerLocation from Person.Address PA
 left join Person.BusinessEntityAddress PBA ON PBA.AddressID=PA.AddressID
 left join Sales.Customer SC ON SC.CustomerID = PBA.BusinessEntityID  
 left join Sales.Store SS ON SS.BusinessEntityID=SC.StoreID
 left join Person.Person PP ON PP.BusinessEntityID = PBA.BusinessEntityID
 WHERE CustomerID IS NOT NULL 
 AND @dest >= (@or.STDistance(SpatialLocation)*0.62)
```

I expect it to accept the query and create the two @dest and @or parameters, but it doesn't. I checked the query for cases too. Any ideas please?

Comment: Looks like SSRS is not recognizing your parameters. try setting some default values for those two variable in SSRS and see if you get any result

Comment: I just tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this from a stored proc or embedded into SSRS?

Comment: Its an embedded data set.

Comment: Try a stored proc to see if it creates the parameters.

Comment: When you say it is not working are you getting any specific errors?

Comment: It gives the familiar error for checking connection to database and checking the syntax. When I click on details, it gives me only this statement: "Cannot call methods on nvarchar."

Comment: Check and make sure the security is set correctly to your data source and it has the permissions it needs to the database.

Comment: Checked the connection, its fine. In fact the query has no issue when I comment the last part of the query. It gives me the error because of this part: @or.STDistance(SpatialLocation)*0.62.   Do you think it is because of the STDistance function? I also noticed that when creating a new parameter, you cannot set its datatype to be geometry. Is it possible that SSRS does not accept parameters with geometry data type?

Comment: Is @or  defined in your dataset parameters page?

Comment: I believe the `Cannot call methods on nvarchar` is the key.  It is expecting a NVARCHAR result and can't do math on a non-integer entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved! SSRS does not realize a parameter with type geography. So, I first cast the parameter before using it in the STDistance function like this:

```
@dest >= cast(@or as geography).STDistance(SpatialLocation)*0.62
```

Thanks for everybody's help!